# How to create Drop Down Pop Up View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipopovercontroller

I want to show a drop-down menu on button click.I follow the below link for this.

```
https://richardallen.me/2014/11/28/popovers.html
```

But my button is in table view cell and I want to show the popup on below the button.I searched a lot and find the way by using popovers. But I don't know how to use and show it.If I follow the above link then below error is shown.And popup is shown on full screen.So please help me.

```
/Base.lproj/Main.storyboard:%20Couldn't%20compile%20connection:%20<IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection:%200x7fc9f5fa6330%20(KPd-LK-kJS)%20source=<IBProxyObject:%200x7fc9f5fa6020%20(mgH-pb-OhC)%20'Placeholder%20for%20UIStoryboardPopoverPresentationSegueTemplate%20with%20OID%20qoG-n8-Yu0'>%20property=anchorView%20destination=<IBUIButton:%200x7fc9f796dd40%20(xk1-Vu-vnj)%20'Anchor%20View'>>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

To create a dropdown using tableview and popover was little bit time consuming work but luckily we have an alternative solution for that use this [library](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown) very easy to use

**Initialization:**

```
let dropDown = DropDown()

// The view to which the drop down will appear on
dropDown.anchorView = view // UIView or UIBarButtonItem

// The list of items to display. Can be changed dynamically
dropDown.dataSource = ["Car", "Motorcycle", "Truck"]
```

**Handle selection:**

```
// Action triggered on selection
dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
  print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
}

// Will set a custom width instead of the anchor view width
dropDownLeft.width = 200
```

**Display actions:**

```
dropDown.show()
dropDown.hide()
```

Hope this will help you